# How to play an mp3 file located in a package?

Tags: java, file-io

How would i set the directory of the following code to play an mp3 file inside of the selected package?

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("song.mp3");
```

Also just another quick question: How would i add a pause button for the following code?

```
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("song.mp3");
    Player playMP3 = new Player(fis);
    playMP3.play();
} catch (Exception exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Failed to play the file.");
}
```

Comment: To pause, you will likely need to play your Player in a different thread so that the `play()` method doesn't block. then hopefully PLayer will have a `pause()` method that you can call when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the resources in your classpath (even when sealed in the JAR) by using the [`ClassLoader#getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) and [`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) methods.

For example:

```
InputStream is = ThisClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("packagename/song.mp3");
// don't forget to close the stream
```